# the_post_thumbnail ignores size parameter

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm inserting an image in my theme as follows:

```
the_post_thumbnail('large');
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<img class="wp-post-image" width="660" height="440" sizes="(max-width: 660px) 100vw, 660px" srcset="/uploads/IMG-1024x683.jpg 1024w, /uploads/IMG-300x200.jpg 300w, /uploads/IMG-768x512.jpg 768w, /uploads/IMG-254x169.jpg 254w, /uploads/IMG-578x385.jpg 578w, /uploads/IMG-665x443.jpg 665w, /uploads/IMG-1600x1067.jpg 1600w" src="/uploads/IMG-1024x683.jpg">
```

Notice `width="660" height="440"` and `sizes="(max-width: 660px) 100vw, 660px"` which doesn't correlate with the size defined for `large` in Media Settings > Image sizes which is supposed to be 1024 x 1024.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

WordPress uses `min( intval($content_width), $max_width )` inside `image_constrain_size_for_editor` for `large` image size.

As I can see your `$content_width` is set to 660. So, change the `$content_width` in your `functions.php` file to the `1024` or whatever you need. For full-width layout, it's better to remove it.

Example: `$GLOBALS['content_width'] = 1600`. That's it.

If you don't know what `content_width` is, see **[Content Width](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width)** for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing right.  Just miss one step.  I guess you upload image before change the size of large in setting. Final step is Regenerated thumbnail.  Just install the plugin with same name,  go to Tool > Regenerate thumbnail and click. ;)

Comment: I did not change the setting for 'large' at all. 1024 is the default for 'large'.

Comment: Default large size is 640. Can you first still install thu plugin I said and try regenerate thumbnail.

Comment: If it's not work.  Scan your code for the function that adjusted thumbnail size. Like: add_image_size or set_post_thumbnail_size

Comment: I did upload a brand new image, problem remains.

Comment: I think there is some code that alter the behavior of thumbnail.  Can you do my second advise

Comment: Did regenerate the images (alongside uploading a new one). Problem remains.

Comment: Sorry,  i did not ne clear.  If upload new image remains problem mean that regenerate thumbnail won't help.  You want to try scan your theme code base,  as my third comment. Not second :(

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'large', false);


<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image[0]);?>" alt="">
```